# Django, environment variables. Error: SMTPRecipientsRefused at /password_reset/

Tags: python, django, environment-variables

it's my first post here.

I'm learning Django, and i'm trying to send an email to reset my password. There is one problem..

When I send an email with my username and password assigned to these constants, everything works well:

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'abc.def@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'Abc123'
```

But when i try to use environment variables instead:

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
```

i got an error

**SMTPRecipientsRefused at /password_reset/**

**{'abc.def@gmail.com': (501, b': sender address must contain a domain')}**

Am I doing something wrong?
Maybe I should use environment variables in different ways?

In advance, thanks for your help, guys!

Comment: try this : EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER').decode("utf-8") or EMAIL_HOST_USER = str(os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER'), 'utf-8')

Comment: @Ro0t I tried both, but i got an errors: 'object has no attribute decode' and 'need a bytes-like object, NoneType found'

Comment: you can post the output of print(os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER'))?

Comment: @Ro0t All i got after print(os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')) is only 'None'. I don't get it, what am i doing wrong with environment variables?

Comment: do you use this syntax to set variables? os.environ['EMAIL_USER'] = 'abc.def@gmail.com'

Comment: @Ro0t Well, honestly - no. I use only this syntax: "EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')". But where can i place this code that you show me, so nobody can find it with my email and password? Thanks.

Comment: read this article [link](https://able.bio/rhett/how-to-set-and-get-environment-variables-in-python--274rgt5)

Answer (score 1):

Hi I once ran into the same problem you are experiencing, but the simple solution is to exit you code editor or open it again and all should now be fixed, the problem is caused by system delays or deadlock.